# Cross-referencing functions from other submodule in Documenter.jl

Tags: documentation, julia, cross-reference

Given a module hierarchy like

```
module A
    module B; function foo end; end
    module C
        """
            bar(x)

        Like [`foo`](@ref), but more `bar`.
        """
        function bar end
    end
end
```

How could I cross-reference `foo` from the docstring of `bar` using [Documenter.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl)? I have tried `A.B.foo`, `B.foo`, and `..B.foo` without success.

Comment: What do you mean by "cross-reference"? Are you saying one would be able to do `?A.C.bar` and then click on the highlighted `foo` in help mode and trigger `?A.B.foo` ? I haven't seen that with other functions, I've only seen highlighting (as you've done).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou While the Julia REPL does not have that feature, [Documenter does](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax.html#@ref-link-1).

Comment: Ah, I do apologise, I must have missed it in the title earlier!  (also I was not aware of Documenter.jl)  :)

Comment: @FengyangWang did you get this figured out? I'm in a similar situation now, getting doc reference errors and not sure what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, both `B.foo` and `C.bar` needs to (i) have docstrings and (ii) be in the markdown file, e.g. in a [Documenter `@docs` block](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax/#@docs-block-1).

````
```@docs
A.B.foo
A.C.bar
```
````

in order to cross-reference between them. Second, the binding `B.foo` must be visible inside the `C` module. This can be achieved by, for example, adding `import ..B: foo` in the `C` module (or adding `export foo` in `B` and `using ..B` in `C`). Here is a working example:

```
module A
    module B
        "foo function"
        function foo end
    end
    module C
        import ..B: foo
        """
            bar(x)

        Like [`foo`](@ref), but more `bar`.
        """
        function bar end
    end
end # module
```